# tools to extract data from Airbnb using R

Tags: r

When I tried to use the following package and wanted to extract the data from Airbnb,it failed.

```
library('devtools')
devtools::install_github("airbnb/Rbnb")
Downloading GitHub repo airbnb/Rbnb@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/airbnb/Rbnb/zipball/master
Error in stop(github_error(request)) : Not Found (404)
```

Does it have any other methods to download data from Aribnb?

Answer (score 1):

It is because the github url is invalid. https://api.github.com/repos/airbnb/Rbnb/zipball/master

And the error is specified at the bottom of you output.

```
Error in stop(github_error(request)) : Not Found (404)
```

Comment: also airbnb do not have support for R language. Please see the supported languages in their github page.